# How to get access to variables from outer Block in nested one?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I trying to code some simple brainf*ck executor with C# extension trees.
But I can't make loops work.

I have something like this as imput: `++++++++++++++++++++[>>+<++<-]>.>.`
And after the building from CST:

```cs
() => {
    int index;
    LazyDictionary<int, char> lent;
    index = 0;
    lent = #LazyDictionary<int, char>;
    lent[index] = (char)(lent[index] + 20);
    while (true) {
        if (lent[index] == '') {
            break;
        } else {
            index += (int)2;
            lent[index] = (char)(lent[index] + 1);
            index -= (int)1;
            lent[index] = (char)(lent[index] + 2);
            index -= (int)1;
            lent[index] = (char)(lent[index] - 1);
        }
    };
    index += (int)1;
    Console.Write(lent[index]);
    index += (int)1;
    Console.Write(lent[index]);
}
```

It looks like thit should work, but the problem is variables.

Statements in the `while` loop is a nested `ExpressionBlock` and any using of `lent` or `index` lead to exception like:

> Variable 'index' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

My code for building loop is something like this

```cs
cstLoopNode.Inner.Visit(this);

var prebody = Buffer.Pop();
var breakLabel = Expression.Label();
var condition = Expression.Equal(CurrentLentValueExpression, Expression.Constant('\0'));
var loopStopper = Expression.IfThenElse(condition, Expression.Break(breakLabel), prebody);

Buffer.Push(Expression.Loop(loopStopper, breakLabel));
```

The variable `prebody` contains a Block of inner statements. If I add variables when create the Block, it creates new variables into the body with same names. If I don't add them, I don't have this variables and it can't get access to ones form outer Block.

Is there a way for create a nested block of statements which can get access to variables from the outside block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a block using `Expression.Block` you give a collection of local variables.  Those should be visible within the block and any sub-blocks.  You will have to bubble up the needed variables to the declaration of the Block if you don't know them until you traverse.

See [BlockExpression.Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.blockexpression.variables?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Expressions_BlockExpression_Variables)